# Include Swipe views with tabs in a fragment

Tags: android

I know there is already a lot of thread about when should we use fragements or activities, I read a lot of them but i'm still confused about it.

Here's a description of the context:

I would like to create an app with 3 screens. It is, I think, a really common app. I created three fragments called in order:

- The first one is the login page
- The second one is a list of items
- The third one is the detail of an item from the list.

But now, I would like to replace the second fragment (the list of items) by three lists wrapped into a [Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html).

So here's the general question: **Is there a way to get the tab action bar and the whole swipe view thing in a fragment ?** I have the feeling that I should make an activity but then, i would loose the flexibility that fragments offers to build the UI for tablets (in my case, displaying fragments two and three on the same screen).

Thanks

Comment: There is just one rule about when to use `Fragments`: **ALWAYS**.

Comment: That's what I would like. But i don't understand how could I do that when one of my fragment needs to include what is showed in the google example about swipe views.

Comment: Wait, what Xaver said is wrong. You should not use fragments for situations where an Activity would make more sense. Having 1 activity for an entire app is only good if the app has one basic functionality (like a newsfeed). I would recommend having the Login page be a separate Activity. All Apps do that since it provides a lot more security, and makes more sense. Have the second view be three fragments embedded into swipe views in a second Activity with tabbed views.